# Is this type of definite integral defined?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I was trying to generalise the definite integral in the following way:

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and let $\phi:(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined in some neighbourhood of zero. For a (sufficiently fine) partition $P:a=x_0<x_1< \dots<x_n=b$ of $[a,b]$ define $$U(P,f,\phi)=\sum_{i=1}^n M_i \phi(\Delta x_i) $$ and

$$ L(P,f,\phi)=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i \phi(\Delta x_i)$$

where for all $i$ $M_i:=\sup_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)$ and $m_i:=\inf_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)$. We define further

$$\overline{\int_a^b} f(x) \phi(dx):=\inf_{P |[a,b]} U(P,f,\phi) $$
and

$$\underline{\int_a^b} f(x) \phi(dx):=\sup_{P |[a,b]} L(P,f,\phi).$$

If the last two values coincides, we name their common value $\int_a^b f(x) \phi(dx)$.

---

I have a few questions regarding this definition:

1. Has this been done before? If so, what is this integral called?
2. What are minimalistic conditions on the function $\phi$ so that the integral exists? (My guess is continuity and $\phi(0)=0$.)
3. Is it true that if $\phi$ is differentiable and fixes zero then $\int_a^b f(x) \phi(dx)=\phi'(0) \int_a^b f(x)dx$?

Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the second question, consider $f=1$, $\phi(h)=\sqrt{|h|}$. I suspect you want at least a $Lip_1$ condition at the origin. I suspect that the answer to 3 is yes, and that this is actually quite simple, just write it down and use the fact that $\phi(h) = h\phi'(0) + o(h)$.